# Sitecore SXA. Style not applying to any of my custom components

Tags: sitecore

I created a custom component.
I also created a custom Style with the corresponding css class and added the components to the Available Renderings. The styles show up correctly in the Experience Editor

.
[image]
Here is the markup:

```
<div class="section component full-image">
    <div class="container">
    //Rest of the code
    </div>
</div>
```

If I apply this style to any of the out-of-the-box components, it gets applied. However, it does not apply to my component. What Am I missing?

[image]

Applied to OOTB components like the rich text box

[image]

Not applied to my component

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, Sitecore didn't like a "section" class in the parent div. Removing it works